# "Glossary of terms" for Ethereum components

Tags: ether, gas, documentation

very new to all this I'd think a bit of defining term's and getting started to know how some key components (like `Ethereum`, `Ether`, `Gas`, `Token`, etc.)
 relate to each like other would help a lot in basic understanding.

So, is there a **Glossary of terms** or something similar
 available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to understand what's going on start at the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) and study it until it sinks in. I read it five times the first ten weeks I was in the space. Best thing I ever did.

Yes. Maybe it's a bit odd to suggest that someone who is 'very new' to the field starts with this famously difficult document. But if you're interested in the "words," all of them (along with their definitive definitions) are here.

Comment: truly a good read even though it's pretty hard to digest

Comment: it's famously hard to digest because the author basically made up math symbols.

Answer (score 1):

[@Thomas's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28488/16301) to refer the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) would be ideal to get a thorough and formal understanding.

If you need a very quick reference Ethereum [Github wiki Glossary](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Glossary), which let you get a general idea what these terms are. And [White Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) for a general understanding about how ethereum works, but less mathematical and formal than the yellow paper.